# Iterating through user input and a list

Tags: python, iteration

I need to match user input to some keywords held in a list.

I have tried several ways to do this, using for, if and while.  Even thought enumerate would be best but cant seem to put it together.  I need to take into account the user may input several words. Eventually the code will be related to something else and open files related to the keywords.

Sample code:

```
shopping = [
    'bananas',
    'apples',
    'chocolate',
    'coffee',
    'bread',
    'eggs',
    'vimto'
    ]

need = input ("please input what you need ")
need = need.lower()
need = need.split()
index = 0
while index < len(shopping):
    for word in need:
        if word == shopping[index]:
            print ("Added to basket")
            index +=1

        if word != shopping[index]:
            index +=1
```

I also need the code to print a response if the input doesn't match a keyword. At the moment the keyword is found, but if the user inputs anything after the keyword, errors occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
shopping = [
    'bananas',
    'apples',
    'chocolate',
    'coffee',
    'bread',
    'eggs',
    'vimto'
    ]

need = input ("please input what you need ")
need = need.lower()
need = need.split()
error = False
for word in need:
    if word in shopping:
        pass
    else:
        error = True

if Error: print ("Not on the list")
else: print ("Added to basket")
```

Comment: Thank you, if I input several words around the keyword it prints off "Not on the list" for each word, Sorry to be a pain, but do you know how to stop this so it only prints off once, at the end of iterating through the user input?

Comment: Thank you so much for this, It got to the point I was over complicating and couldn't see the wood through the trees.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need these crazy loops.

Just simply

```
if thing in shopping_list:
    # this is good!
else:
    # do something
```

All in all, your code will look like this:

```
need = input("Input what you need: ")
need = [x.strip() for x in need.lower().strip().split()]

for thing in need:
    if thing in shopping_list:
        print("Added this!")
    else:
        print("No, man, you aren't buying this!")
```